# What does this error mean? I cannot seem to get this code to work

Tags: lua

Im trying to get this lua code to run but cannot seem to get it to work. Whenever i run it i get this error that i cant seem to avoid no matter how many times i edit it.
Can anybody find a solution for this? I have been searching all over the web to no avail.
This is the error i get

input:58: unexpected symbol near eof

Here is the code:

```
-- Made By Vincent


local ScreenGui = Instance.new("ScreenGui")
local Main = Instance.new("Frame")
local RoundedCorners = Instance.new("UICorner")
local BlackHoleGun = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner = Instance.new("UICorner")
local GoldenPistol = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner_2 = Instance.new("UICorner")
local CrazyFuturisticMinigun = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner_3 = Instance.new("UICorner")
local BiochemicalBlaster = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner_4 = Instance.new("UICorner")
local SpaceRifle = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner_5 = Instance.new("UICorner")
local LavaPistol = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner_6 = Instance.new("UICorner")
local Scar = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner_7 = Instance.new("UICorner")
local RayGun = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner_8 = Instance.new("UICorner")
local SniperRifle = Instance.new("TextButton")
local UICorner_9 = Instance.new("UICorner")

--Properties:

ScreenGui.Parent = game.CoreGui

Main.Name = "Main"
Main.Parent = ScreenGui
Main.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
Main.Position = UDim2.new(0.383399218, 0, 0.121621616, 0)
Main.Size = UDim2.new(0, 426, 0, 211)
Main.Active = true
Main.Draggable = true

RoundedCorners.Name = "RoundedCorners"
RoundedCorners.Parent = Main

BlackHoleGun.Name = "Black Hole Gun"
BlackHoleGun.Parent = ScreenGui
BlackHoleGun.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
BlackHoleGun.Position = UDim2.new(0.393280655, 0, 0.136486486, 0)
BlackHoleGun.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
BlackHoleGun.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
BlackHoleGun.Text = "Black Hole Gun"
BlackHoleGun.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
BlackHoleGun.TextScaled = true
BlackHoleGun.TextSize = 14.000
BlackHoleGun.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
BlackHoleGun.TextWrapped = true
BlackHoleGun.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
    local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

    local Arguments = {
        [1] = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = "Black Hole Gun"
            },
            [2] = {
                [1] = false
            }
        }
    }

    Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))



    UICorner.Parent = BlackHoleGun
    

GoldenPistol.Name = "Golden Pistol"
GoldenPistol.Parent = ScreenGui
GoldenPistol.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
GoldenPistol.Position = UDim2.new(0.533596873, 0, 0.136486486, 0)
GoldenPistol.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
GoldenPistol.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
GoldenPistol.Text = "Golden Pistol"
GoldenPistol.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
GoldenPistol.TextScaled = true
GoldenPistol.TextSize = 14.000
GoldenPistol.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
    GoldenPistol.TextWrapped = true
    NAMEOFBUTTONHERE.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

        local Arguments = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = {
                    [1] = "Golden Pistol"
                },
                [2] = {
                    [1] = false
                }
            }
        }

        Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))



    end)

UICorner_2.Parent = GoldenPistol

CrazyFuturisticMinigun.Name = "Crazy Futuristic Minigun"
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.Parent = ScreenGui
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.Position = UDim2.new(0.673913062, 0, 0.136486486, 0)
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.Text = "Crazy Futuristic Minigun"
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.TextScaled = true
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.TextSize = 14.000
CrazyFuturisticMinigun.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
    CrazyFuturisticMinigun.TextWrapped = true
    NAMEOFBUTTONHERE.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

        local Arguments = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = {
                    [1] = "Crazy Futuristic Minigun"
                },
                [2] = {
                    [1] = false
                }
            }
        }

        Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))



    end)

UICorner_3.Parent = CrazyFuturisticMinigun

BiochemicalBlaster.Name = "Biochemical Blaster"
BiochemicalBlaster.Parent = ScreenGui
BiochemicalBlaster.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
BiochemicalBlaster.Position = UDim2.new(0.393280655, 0, 0.231081083, 0)
BiochemicalBlaster.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
BiochemicalBlaster.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
BiochemicalBlaster.Text = "Biochemical Blaster"
BiochemicalBlaster.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
BiochemicalBlaster.TextScaled = true
BiochemicalBlaster.TextSize = 14.000
BiochemicalBlaster.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
    BiochemicalBlaster.TextWrapped = true
    NAMEOFBUTTONHERE.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

        local Arguments = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = {
                    [1] = "Biochemical Blaster"
                },
                [2] = {
                    [1] = false
                }
            }
        }

        Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))
    end)

UICorner_4.Parent = BiochemicalBlaster

SpaceRifle.Name = "Space Rifle"
SpaceRifle.Parent = ScreenGui
SpaceRifle.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
SpaceRifle.Position = UDim2.new(0.533596873, 0, 0.231081083, 0)
SpaceRifle.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
SpaceRifle.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
SpaceRifle.Text = "Space Rifle"
SpaceRifle.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
SpaceRifle.TextScaled = true
SpaceRifle.TextSize = 14.000
SpaceRifle.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
    SpaceRifle.TextWrapped = true
    NAMEOFBUTTONHERE.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

        local Arguments = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = {
                    [1] = "Space Rifle"
                },
                [2] = {
                    [1] = false
                }
            }
        }

        Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))


    end)

UICorner_5.Parent = SpaceRifle

LavaPistol.Name = "Lava Pistol"
LavaPistol.Parent = ScreenGui
LavaPistol.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
LavaPistol.Position = UDim2.new(0.672924936, 0, 0.231081083, 0)
LavaPistol.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
LavaPistol.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
LavaPistol.Text = "Lava Pistol"
LavaPistol.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
LavaPistol.TextScaled = true
LavaPistol.TextSize = 14.000
LavaPistol.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
    LavaPistol.TextWrapped = true
    NAMEOFBUTTONHERE.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

        local Arguments = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = {
                    [1] = "Lava Pistol"
                },
                [2] = {
                    [1] = false
                }
            }
        }

        Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))


    end)

UICorner_6.Parent = LavaPistol

Scar.Name = "Scar"
Scar.Parent = ScreenGui
Scar.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
Scar.Position = UDim2.new(0.392292529, 0, 0.322972983, 0)
Scar.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
Scar.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
Scar.Text = "Scar"
Scar.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
Scar.TextScaled = true
Scar.TextSize = 14.000
Scar.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
    Scar.TextWrapped = true
    NAMEOFBUTTONHERE.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

        local Arguments = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = {
                    [1] = "SCAR"
                },
                [2] = {
                    [1] = false
                }
            }
        }

        Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))


    end)

UICorner_7.Parent = Scar

RayGun.Name = "Ray Gun"
RayGun.Parent = ScreenGui
RayGun.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
RayGun.Position = UDim2.new(0.533596873, 0, 0.322972983, 0)
RayGun.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
RayGun.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
RayGun.Text = "Ray Gun"
RayGun.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
RayGun.TextScaled = true
RayGun.TextSize = 14.000
RayGun.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
    RayGun.TextWrapped = true
    NAMEOFBUTTONHERE.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

        local Arguments = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = {
                    [1] = "Ray Gun"
                },
                [2] = {
                    [1] = false
                }
            }
        }

        Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))



    end)

UICorner_8.Parent = RayGun

SniperRifle.Name = "Sniper Rifle"
SniperRifle.Parent = ScreenGui
SniperRifle.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
SniperRifle.Position = UDim2.new(0.672924936, 0, 0.322972983, 0)
SniperRifle.Size = UDim2.new(0, 121, 0, 49)
SniperRifle.Font = Enum.Font.GothamBold
SniperRifle.Text = "Sniper Rifle"
SniperRifle.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 219, 0)
SniperRifle.TextScaled = true
SniperRifle.TextSize = 14.000
SniperRifle.TextStrokeColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(174, 38, 148)
    SniperRifle.TextWrapped = true
    NAMEOFBUTTONHERE.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        local Remote = game.Workspace.__THINGS.__REMOTES['weaponequipped']

        local Arguments = {
            [1] = {
                [1] = {
                    [1] = "Sniper Rifle"
                },
                [2] = {
                    [1] = false
                }
            }
        }

        Remote:FireServer(unpack(Arguments))



    end)

UICorner_9.Parent = SniperRifle
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question.  Don't use pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/RvKUuwFC

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to edit your question to 1) make the subject line clearer and include the error and 2) provide a minimal code example that will reproduce the error.

Answer (score 3):

With time you'll learn how to find such errors quickly. If you have no idea where to start, there are several ways to approach this.

1. read the code and in your mind check what is missing ( pro level )
2. delete everything from your code that is syntactically correct

   in your example you'll end up with `BlackHoleGun.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()` which is an incomplete function call with an imcomplete function definition. So you know that you have to put an `end` at the end of that function's body and that you need to a `)` to close that function call.
3. count things that come in pairs (most editors can do that).

   in your example you have 36`{`, 36`}`, 54`[`, 54`]`, 105`(`, **104**`)`  whoops! -> 1 `)` short!

   you have 8 `end`s for 0 `do` + 0 `then` + 9 `function` -> 1 `end` short!

   now check where those things are missing and add them.

A very good way to avoid such errors is to have your text editor/ide autocomplete pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the end of the function `BlackHoleGun.MouseButton1Down:connect` you are declaring in line 53. There is no closing bracket.
I think you are missing

```
end)
```

after line 67.